# Windows 7 CLI not recognizing commands without specifying extension

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, environment-variables, ruby

I've apparently gone and mucked up my system in a strange way. Windows 7's `cmd` prompt is no longer recognizing any executable or batch files unless I explicitly type their extension.

```
C:\Users\Current> xcopy /?
'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

This is fixed by qualifying it with the `.exe` extension:

```
C:\Users\Current> xcopy.exe /?
< ... all of the help for xcopy shows below, as expected ... >
```

I assumed I'd done something to break my path when xcopy stopped working, but setting it back to a minimum set of things that Windows typically includes has not fixed it. My path is currently as follows:

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\KC\Scripts
```

The only nonstandard thing in there is `C:\KC\Scripts`, which is specified in my User Path. I don't believe that the string is malformed in any way. This happened recently after installing Ruby via the windows RubyInstaller and selecting for it to automatically update my Path. I've since removed anything from the path but what I've posted above, but the error persists.

Is anyone aware of a reason that Windows would stop recognizing programs and batch files in the CLI without explicitly specifying that they are .exe or .bat files?

Comment: Are you sure you are actually in a command prompt. This is the default behavior of a Powershell prompt which may be what you are actually in.

Comment: @EBGreen You can run `xcopy` (for example) in Powershell without specifying the extension.

Comment: Have you rebooted since you change the path back?  Having said that, generally a path issue doesn't usually affect extension usage.  Are you using Windows 7 32-bit or 64-bit?  What's returned if you run `where xcopy.exe`?

Comment: What about your `PATHEXT` variable? Should be something like `PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`, the syntax is like the `PATH` variable with semicolon separators. Add output from `set path` command, please.

Comment: Have you tried a system restore?

Comment: @JosefZ Could you post that as an answer? It looks like the Ruby Installer screwed up my PATHEXT and replaced it with JUST `.RB;.RBW`.

Comment: Consider tag your question `ruby` as well. Could help others with the same `RubyInstaller` problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible reasons for Windows `cmd` shell error

```
'foo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

Two environment variables are close bound with shell command execution: `PATH` and `PATHEXT`.

- The `PATH` environment variable defines the Windows search path, i.e. a list of directories that are searched when the command shell attempts to locate an *executable* file.
- The `PATHEXT` environment variable defines the list of file extensions checked by Windows when searching for an *executable* file.

And any file extension could be considered *executable*: if a file extension is associated with an application, the shell executes the appropriate application. Here *is associated* stands for the same as *is defined as default shell action* in the Windows registry for a particular file extension.

Here is a good introduction to all this topic: [The Windows NT Command Shell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. As explained in my comment above, the `RubyInstaller` program mangled my `PATHEXT` variable when choosing to update file associations, leaving me without any of the standard extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this with a batch file I use to copy an Access front-end app to the user's local machines. Their environment is a mix of Windows 7 & 8 and 32-64 bit machines.

I noticed that the xcopy.exe was both in the System32 and the SysWOW64 folders and I wondered if there was some conflict.

I copied the xcopy.exe into the folder where the batch file resides and it now seems to be working.